# How to restore multiple files from a prefix in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I have plenty of objects in AWS S3 Glacier, I'm trying to restore some of them which are on the same prefix (aka folder). However I can't find a way to restore them all at once, it might be worth mentioning that some of the elements in this prefix are prefixes themselves which I also want to restore.

Comment: That is correct. The `RestoreObject()` command only restores a single object. Have you tried selecting the folder in the Amazon S3 management console and choosing "Initiate Restore"? Or did you want to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to get it working. I had to write a simple bash script that iterates through all the objects in the bucket's prefix which are `GLACIER` or `DEEP_ARCHIVE` depending on the case. So there are two components to this:

First, you need a file with all the objects:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket someBucket --prefix 
some/prefix/within/the/bucket/ --query "Contents[?StorageClass== 'GLACIER']" 
-- output text | awk '{print $2}' > somefile.txt
```

The `list-objects-v2` will list all the objects in the prefix, with the `awk '{print $2}'` command we'll make sure the resulting file is iterable and contains just the names of the objects.

Finally, iterate through the file restoring the objects:

```
for i in $(cat somefile.txt); 
do
    #echo "Sending request for object: $i"
    aws s3api restore-object --bucket $BUCKET --key $i --restore-request Days=$DAYS
    #echo "Request sent for object: $i"  
done
```

You can uncomment the `echo` commands to make the execution more verbose but it's unnecessary for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished easily with `s3cmd` (https://s3tools.org/s3cmd).

You can use the `restore` command with the `--recursive` option. There is no need to gather a list of the objects you want to restore first. You just need to specify the days to restore the objects and the priority of the restore.

Example:

```
s3cmd restore  --recursive s3://BUCKET-NAME/[PREFIX/TO/OBJECTS] --restore-days=60 --restore-priority=standard
```